# Debugging fails with QtCreator on OSX

Tags: c++, macos, qt, debugging, qt-creator

I have OSX Yosemite 10.10.5, QtCreator 4.1.0, Qt 5.7.0 and Xcode 7.2.1.

If I write any native C++ program in QtCreator (console, gui - anything) I am unable to debug that program from QtCreator. Breakpoints get ignored, the program executes without pause and runs to completion no matter what I try.

I have tried the Xcode's LLDb, system GDB and Homebrew GDB as debuggers. the versions of GDB fail to start. Homebrew GDB has been codesigned.

This all used to (a few year back) just work beautifully and I am at a loss as to what might have changed.

Curiously, if I generate an exception inside the program - like accessing through a null pointer, the debugger shows me where this happens in just the way I would expect so, presumably, the debugger is running but simply treating me with complete disdain.

I know there are many versions of this question but none seem to address the problem adequately or offer workable solutions, or they apply to much older versions of the products.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I now work with very similar configuration and it debugs like a charm. Please post your project build / compiler / run settings and also debugger settings. You may use screenshots for that. I cannot remember if I did anything special to enable the configuration. On OSX I use Apple own compiler from the framework.

Comment: This can for example happen if you actually do not compile with debug symbols, or if the file paths in the debug information do not match the file paths that you opened in Qt Creator (afair this can happen when compiling in `/tmp`). The "Window > Views > Debugger Log" in Debug mode can possibly shed some light as well. Regarding GDB from Homebrew: Qt Creator requires python scripting support in the debugger, maybe this is not enabled for the Homebrew version?

Comment: @E4z9: The Debugger Log is unhelpfully verbose. No obvious error messages or warnings appear to be present. However, I did note that the setupInferior script call contains this: "breakonmain":0 which explains why the program just executes immediately. I can see no place to set that behaviour.

Comment: @AlexanderVX: postings the configs represents a number of large images. I will see if I can do that.

Comment: Or maybe links to the actual image location.

Comment: @AlexanderVX: OK - I think the settings you want are here:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0BwDTUHl0BrFiS1A3Q01iajR5TlU?usp=sharing

Comment: I found 2 significant (besides checks in General that won't affect) things different with mine: the only debugger I have set up is /usr/bin/lldb and my Qt Creator has a bit different UI and its version is Qt Creator 4.1.0
Based on Qt 5.7.0 (Clang 7.0 (Apple), 64 bit)

Built on Aug 24 2016 15:09:37

From revision 8c80a8626   And my project is built with Clang 64 bit.

Comment: Interesting that your QtCreator has a different UI. Mine has the exact same version information as yours.

Cant remove the auto-detected debuggers settings. Changing the debugger to be the /usr/bin/lldb makes no difference to the outcome.

If I debug from the command line with /usr/bin/lldb, it behaves exactly as it should.

I am beginning to think that the installation of QtCreator fouled up.

Comment: Build & Run / Device / Local PC (Default for Desktop) differs from yours Run Locally (Default for Desktop). That made me to think UI is a bit different however that may depend on something. Glad that you resolved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This version of qtCreator (4.1.0) saw the return of the warning about having the build directory at the same level as the project directory. In Windows, this is done automatically. My mac installation does not get it right. (I may have messed a while back - cannot remember).

So - if the build directory is inside the project directory, debugging fails. Move the build directory up to the same level as the project directory and everything seems to work fine.

You can set the default build directory in the preferences/Build & Run dialogue. The path should start with ../

[image: Build and Run settings]

You will need to think about the folder structure before setting up the project unless you want build folders appearing in awkward places. So, a project folder structure like this is OK:

[image: correct project folder structure]

But one like this is not:

[image: bad project folder sructure]

If this was already obvious to you, great. I have been messing with this for ages.

Many thanks to those who replied and anyone else who took the time to read the question. What helped e find it was the suggestion by @AlexanderVX that his setup was the same as mine but his worked. The only bit of my setup he could not see in the screenshots was the start of the build path. So that was the clue.